# How to get latest version information from marketplace

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am trying to find a way to get the latest version number of windows phone 7 from the market place. It seems like the API does not have build in method to do this. Some suggestion I found mention about creating a web service to get the information. Does anyone have a more specific detail on how to do this? Where do I call the web service to get this information?

Comment: Do you mean the latest version of the Operating System? Why is the Marketplace involved in this?

Comment: What's the reasoning behind this? If you created a web-service for this, it would be where its relevant for your application.

Answer (score 0):

This is not from marketplace, but you can parse this page:

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsphone/en-us/howto/wp7/basics/update-history.aspx

Comment: The entire question is kind of pointless, unless it gets really specific down to a carrier / device level. (i.e. So what if 8107 is released, I haven't seen it on my lg quantum on at&t)